# Correct usage of generic wildcards

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to get this code working for half an hour now and I do not know, how I should fix this. Everything else doesn't complain, but the compiler keeps screaming at me that `configurable.value` is not the same type as `configurable.defaultValue`. I am quite confused as `?` is supposed to be a wildcard, right?

I am pretty new to generics, so I am a bit lost. I did not find any solution yet.

Is there a solution, which does not produce any warnings or errors?

ConfigurationManager.class is here:

```
public class ConfigurationManager
{
    private final List<Configurable<?>> config;

    public ConfigurationManager()
    {
        config = new ArrayList<Configurable<?>>();
    }

    public void register(Configurable<?> entry)
    {
        this.config.add(entry);
    }

    public void resetAll()
    {
        for(Configurable<?> configurable : this.config)
        {
            //Problem here
            //Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#3-of ? to capture#2-of ?
            configurable.value = configurable.defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Configurable.class is here:

```
public class Configurable<T>
{
    ResourceAddress address;
    protected T value;
    protected final T defaultValue;

    public Configurable(ResourceAddress address, T defaultValue)
    {
        this.address = address;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }

    public ResourceAddress getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setValue(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's probably an issue with the strict interpretation of the LHS and RHS types. It would be clearer to avoid the issue entirely with a `protected void resetToDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't recognize that `value` and `defaultValue` belong to the same object, so it doesn't know they have the same type. One solution is to create a type-capturing helper method to call from your loop:

```
<T> void resetValue(Configurable<T> configurable) {
    configurable.value = configurable.defaultValue;
}
```

As @chrylis points out, a better solution would probably be to add an instance method to `Configurable`:

```
public void resetValue() {
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, to put this on `Configurable` in the first place where it belongs.